# How to find the name of a place inside a sentence using NLP

Tags: ruby, nlp

There are sentences like

```
query = "Weather of Moscow"
```

or

```
query = "what is the weather tomorrow in France"
```

I want to find the name of the city. It will be `Moscow` and `France` for both of them.

Do you know any gem that solves this problem?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: "what is the weather tomorrow in France".downcase.include?("france")
i doubt you are looking for something this, if you are aware that the name of country will fall only once in sentence and index is known, keep an array of countries to match.

Comment: If you have `"New Amsterdam"`, do you want both "New Amsterdam" and "Amsterdam", or only "New Amsterdam", or only "Amsterdam" (because New Amsterdam does not exist anymore)?

Answer (score 0):

To extract named entities from the text you can use Named Entity Recognition(NER).

For NER in ruby check this git repo:

https://github.com/mblongii/ruby-ner

and this:

https://github.com/diasks2/ruby-nlp#named-entity-recognition

In python you can do as below:

You can use Spacy NER(Name entity Recognition) for this.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'what is the weather tomorrow in France')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

Output:

```
(u'tomorrow', 20, 28, u'DATE')
(u'France', 32, 38, u'GPE')`
```

**'GPE'** stands for **'Geopolitical entity, i.e. countries, cities, states'**.

To Know more about spacy ner, check this link: [link](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#101)